# How can we load image like apple is doing in his app store?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, asynchronous

Hello guys how apple is loading table view cell image that 
doesn't affect scrolling of 
table view.How fast it is working. I want to make a table view like that which loads 
image directly from URL and it doesn't effect scrolling of UITableview

Comment: upvoted to compensate for the -ve vote. Be nice to someone who is seeking help...

Answer (score 3):

Lazy Loading is the exact term, which you are referring to. (Apple Technologies uses LazyLoading wherever it can be applicable, whether it's iOS or Mac OS X -- and it gives best user experience, too, as user is not forced to wait)

Apple provides sample source code, which performs similar functionality -- [Here is the sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html)

Don't get confused with the `ParseOperation` Class. It is just the separate implementation of the XML Parsing functionality. Though, It is a better approach, You can write it in your own working class (from which you are invoking the connection request.)

Additionally -- Apple has updated this code to use Blocks (GCD).
Hope that will help you...

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to look too far - Apple has this code in the Open - [LazyTables](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html).

If you want to know the magic sauce is the launching of bg thread to download images, after the downloads finish in background, then it updates the UI to show the image.